# How to track down source of weird code insertion

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code 1.10.2 running on macOS Sierra (10.12.3), whenever I type an open paren ( `(` ) followed by two spaces in quick succession, a period ( `( .` ) is inserted in my code. If I type the spaces with a momentary delay in between, nothing happens (no period is inserted).

[image: screen capture]

I recently reformatted my hard drive and reinstalled my OS, so I know I'm working with a very clean box.

I've got 4 plugins installed: Apex, ESLint, ForceCode and Visualforce. I tried disabling all of them and reloading my editor, but that didn't fix the issue.

Is this a bug, a configuration setting, or something else? It's getting really annoying, so I'd like to find a way to make this stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Apparently this is a new MacOS Sierra feature. It's supposed to be turned off by default, but apparently it was enabled, perhaps because I installed a clean copy rather than upgrading.

You can disable this feature by opening Settings > Keyboard > Text and unchecking the "Add period with double-space" option:

[image]

Why on earth anyone would have thought that this feature would be useful I cannot fathom. It doesn't make sense in the context of sentence (since it places a space before and after the period)... but there it is.